# Do arithmetic operators have to promote integral arguments to int?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[cppreference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion):

> In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable.

All the major compilers (g++, clang, and msvc) [say](https://godbolt.org/g/Gr4xqN) that `decltype(a+b)` is `int` when both `a` and `b` are `short`.

However, the standard says:

> [Integral promotions  [conv.prom]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#1)
> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_­t`, `char32_­t`, or `wchar_­t` whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` [...].
>
> [Usual arithmetic conversions [expr.arith.conv]/1.5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5.1)
> -- If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.

I can only see that "can be converted" and I cannot find where it requires integral promotion for arithmetic operators.
Is the cppreference wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were one line away from it. From [expr]/11 (N4659):

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, the integral promotions (7.6) **shall be performed** on both operands. Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:

Emphasis added. [conv.prom] says that they can take place and how they work. [expr]/11 specifies one of the times when they *will* take place.

Comment: That's slightly flimsy wording, if I may say so myself. It says "algorithm A is applied". But once we read the algorithm, it speaks  in terms of what "may happen", not what "should happen".

Comment: @StoryTeller: Right. 7.6 isn't talking about what will happen to every integer everywhere. It's explaining the process of integral promotions, which *can happen*. Someone else decides *when* integer promotions happen. If you use arithmetic on integers, they get promoted. If you *don't* use arithmetic on them, then they *don't* get promoted. That's why it says "can", not "will".

Comment: Yes. And that's the problem. Because for instance, [expr.add]: *"The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or enumeration type."*. Same flimsy wording that points to 7.6 (which is already kinda flimsy). Point being, it's way to subtle a phrasing for a formal specification IMO.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I see nothing flimsy there. "Usual arithmetic conversions" is a techical term, defined explicitly in the standard. "Are performed" means exactly what it says.

Comment: Apparently it's not *quite* as obvious, or the OP wouldn't be confused, and I wouldn't hesitate to bolden the same text myself.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The fact that one person managed to miss a sentence doesn't mean the sentence was not there nor that it wasn't clear. People make mistakes and misread things. That doesn't mean what they were reading wasn't clear.

Comment: We can argue clarity until the chickens come home to roost. If one persons finds something unclear, it doesn't make them "wrong". I don't appreciate that patronizing attitude to be frank.

Comment: The [conv.prom] should be written as "1/ Integral promotions are the following conversions: 2/ A prvalue of an integer type other than [...] **is** converted to a prvalue of type int [...]." and there would be no confusion.

Comment: @Abyx - To contrast, [the C standard does speak in terms of "**is**" and not "**may**"](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2).

Comment: @Abyx: But *everything* in the standard is written this way. All of these processes use "can be" wording. Look up [basic.lookup.qual] or [basic.stc.static]/3. Or just search for "can be". This is the common way the standard defines processes like this which "can be" invoked by various other constructs.

Comment: @StoryTeller: "The following ***may be used*** in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:" That's from your C standard link. Just like in C++, it speaks of possibilities here; whether it actually happens is explained elsewhere.

Comment: @NicolBolas - You should continue reading before basing any claim on it.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Now, take the C 6.3.1.1 section and expand it 5-fold (since C++ has more types and cases for integer promotion). Now, instead of doing it as a list, fold the first sentence into each of the list elements. What you'll have is C++'s section 7.6. The "may be" wording in C is applied once, but it still applies to each separate bullet point. The C++ version simply repeats it, since it doesn't use bullet points.

Comment: @Abyx Uh, no. That wording would be quite bad. [conv.prom] defines conversions that *can be* performed. If you use "is", you're stating that they *are* preformed. Saying "A prvalue of type `bool` **is** converted to a prvalue of type `int`" implies that all bool prvalues are `int`s. The wording is fine as-is.