# C++ auto on int16_t casts to integer

Tags: c++, c++17, auto, decltype

I am pretty new to C++17 and am attempting to understand the `decltype` keyword and how it pairs with `auto`.

Below is a snippet of code that produces an unexpected result.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int16_t mid = 4;
  auto low = mid - static_cast<int16_t>(2);
  auto hi = mid + static_cast<int16_t>(2);

  int16_t val;
  cin >> val;

  val = std::clamp(val,low,hi);

  return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, the compiler tells me there is a mismatch in `clamp` and that `low` and `high` are `int`. If I change `auto` to `int16_t` all is good in the world and all the types are `int16_t` as expected.

The question I'm posing is, **why does `auto` cast `low` and `hi` to `int` when all of the types are `int16_t`?** Is this a good use case for `decltype`?

Even after reading cppreference.com, I don't fully understand how `decltype` works, so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: you can indeed use `decltype(mid) low = mid - ...` or cast the whole expression `auto low = static_cast<int16_t>(mid - ...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c)

Comment: [Do arithmetic operators have to promote integral arguments to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47336098/995714), [Why are integer types promoted during addition in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29817927/995714)...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem isn't with `auto` here. When you subtract two `int16_t` values, the result is an `int`. We can demonstrate it with [this code here](https://ideone.com/THSqP1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void print_type(T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; 
}

int main() {
    int16_t a = 10;
    int16_t b = 20;
    print_type(a);
    print_type(b);
    print_type(a - b); 
    return 0;
}
```

`a` and `b` are both `short int`s, but when you add or subtract them it produces a regular `int`. This is to help prevent overflow / and is also for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

This phenomenon is called the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28142965). It is defined in the C and C++ standards and (roughly said) converts anything smaller than an `int` to an `int`. It converts larger types as well. Take some time and read about it, you'll need it quite often.